# How do I use TKinter for pd.merge function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, tkinter

I'm using TKInter to select two files, and then use pd.merge to do a data transformation. However, I'm having trouble understanding how I can use TkInter to select the type of transformation and column to go off of so the code is flexible.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
files = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title ='Choose two files')

def cleanup():

    file_1 = pd.read_excel(files[0])
    file_2 = pd.read_excel(files[1])

    file_1_left_on_options = ["Id", "Name"]

    master = Tk()

    variable = StringVar(master)
    variable.set(file_1_left_on_options[0])

    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *file_1_left_on_options)
    w.pack()

    file_2_right_on_options = ["ID", "Name"]

   
    master = Tk()

    variable = StringVar(master)
    variable.set(file_2_right_on_options[0]) # default value

     how_options = [
        "left",
        "right", 
        "outer",
        "inner", 
        "cross"
    ]

       master = Tk()

       variable = StringVar(master)
       variable.set(how_options[0]) # default value
```

I used the following code:

```
df = pd.merge(
    left = file_1,
    right = file_2,
    left_on = left_on_options,
    right_on = right_on_options,
    how = how_options)
matched = df.to_csv("matched.csv", index=False)
```

The first dropdown works as expected but the rest of the code doesn't run, it just stops. How can I fix this

Comment: Why do you create instances of `Tk()` inside `cleanup()`? Basically only one instance of `Tk()` is required.